# Public slots not visible in Squish

Tags: qt5, squish

I have a small application, written in Qt, in which the MainWindow class is having 2 public slots namely:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
.
.
.
.
public slots:
    quint8 GetColorCode();
    QString GetRGBColorCode();
.
.
.
};
```

As per the Squish documents, public slots, signals and properties with Q_PROPERTY macro can be accessed directly from Squish environment. Slots and Signals appear under the Squish IDEs method list window.
But unfortunately I am not able to see the above methods in the Squish IDE method list.
Is there any specific way to make the public slots available to Squish?

Regards,
Bikash

Answer (score 0):

Squish for Qt only exposes "public" APIs. You must declare the desired slots public.

As a test I added...

```
public slots:
    quint8 GetColorCode();
    QString GetRGBColorCode();
```

...to *squish_dir/examples/qt/addressbook/mainwindow.h*, and...

```
quint8 MainWindow::GetColorCode()
{
    return 3;
}


QString MainWindow::GetRGBColorCode()
{
    return QString("3");
}
```

...to *squish_dir/examples/qt/addressbook/mainwindow.cpp*, compiled the example and loaded it in Squish.

Afterwards the "Methods" view showed these two methods when selecting the MainWindow object in the "Application Objects" view.